# DefaultPasswordHasher store password as plain text

Tags: cakephp

Am using cakephp 3 and i want to create login sistem on my app. I follow blog tutorial for auth. When i create new user password is stored as plain text, its not hashed. I dont know what  do wrong.  Check my code

I create table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(50),
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(255),
    role VARCHAR(20),
    created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Also i create UsersTable and entity Users

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('users');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
    }
}

class User extends Entity
{

    protected $_accessible = [
        'username' => true,
        'password' => true
    ];

    protected function _setPassword($password) {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
}

// App\Controller\AppController.php
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'index'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            ]
        ]);
```

**And inside UsersController i add:**

```
   public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout');
    }

    // Login
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }

    // Add
    public function add() {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->data);
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add the user.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }
```

Comment: In your entity file User.php, have you specified this line on top??                     use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;

Comment: Yup i have. I slove this with bake

Comment: PASSWORD != password. Always stick ton conventions and mind your casing.